# Rails + Devise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, csrf-protection

Cheers!
I use Devise gem for authenticating users and locally (development env) I always get this ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken exception on `devise::session/create` action, no big deal I thought and added some dirt:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include EmailConcern
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def handle_unverified_request
    true
  end

  ...

end
```

All right, no more authenticity_token exceptions, I don't mind if it happens only in dev env. But! There is another problem - `:authenticate_user!` is never worked, so `current_user` is always nil and I always getting redirected with `401 unauthorized` to new session path again. User's credentials are valid and user exists in the DB.

router.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :coupons

  devise_for :users, path: 'u'
```

What could be the origin of this issue?

`ruby-2.2.2@rails-4.2.0`

Comment: did u try to clear your cache from browser?